# What is the way to only publish sbt documentation?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am aware of publishing `sbt build` but what if I want to publish only documentation generated using `sbt doc`.

Is there anyway if we don't want to publish scala code as a library, while just want to publish documentation?

To make it more clear. I want to host API documentation of sbt same as we do with the library using `sbt publish`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution depends on how you want to consume this documentation later.

If you want to host it as a website, you should probably take a look at [sbt-site](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-site) and [other related plugins](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Community-Plugins.html#Documentation+plugins).

If you want to publish it as an artifact, same way as it happens with `sbt publish` by default, just without jar and sources, you can just add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / packageBin / publishArtifact := false
Compile / packageSrc / publishArtifact := false
```

This will publish only the `-javadoc.jar`, the ivy-xml and the pom-file (or no pom, if you add `publishMavenStyle := false`).

You can check sbt documentation for these options in the [Artifacts section](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Artifacts.html).